# Bash Script to run against all .log files

Tags: bash, unix

I currently have a bash script called (log2csv). While in the current directory I can type in terminal:

`log2csv *.log`

This will run the script on every .log file in the current directory.

Alternatively I can run it against a single .log file with

`log2csv test1.log`

Instead of typing `log2csv *.log`, can I have the *.log included in the script? So I can just type log2csv in the directory and it runs. I know I can alias that, but I rather have the script do it.

Here is the bash script I am running:

```
#!/bin/bash

for path
do 
      base=$(basename "$path")
      noext="${base/.log}"
      [ -e "${noext}.csv" ] && continue
      /Users/joshuacarter/bin/read_scalepack.pl "$path" > "${noext}.csv"

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
for path
```

to:

```
for path in *.log
```

or, perhaps better:

```
names=( "$@" )
if [ "${#names}" = 0 ]
then names=( *.log )
fi
for path in "${names[@]}"
```

and you can consider whether to set options such as `shopt -s nullglob` as well.  This uses shell arrays to handle names with blanks etc in them.  It uses command line arguments if any are given, and the list of files from `*.log` being expanded if there are no command line arguments.